# How to create a barplot using multiple column

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

My data is about boardgames which contain 1 to many catgeories each like this :

```
categorie1 categorie2 categorie3
  Deduction   Medieval  Word Game
  Deduction   Medieval  NA
  Card Game   Medieval  Zombies
     Horror   NA        NA
     Horror   Medieval  Zombies
```

I would like to create a barplot showing the most common categories accross games but i can't figure out how with multiple columns instead of one. Is there a dplyr method ?

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, feel free to accept it as the correct one. If you want to wait and see if a better answer is offered, feel free. You can read more here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is `gather` from the `tidyr` package. This function takes a wide data.frame and makes it a long data.frame. `gather` is easy to use:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Building a sample data.frame like your example data.
df <- data.frame(Boardgame = c("Game1", "Game2", "Game3", "Game4", "Game5"),
             categorie1 = c("Deduction", "Deduction", "Card Game", "Horror", "Horror"),
             categorie2 = c("Medieval", "Medieval", "Medieval", NA, "Medieval"),
             categorie3 = c("Word Game", NA, "Zombies", NA, "Zombies"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Using gather from tidyr and some dplyr functions:
df %>%
  gather(key = "Cat_Label",    # Key is the name of the column that will holdthe old column names
         value = "Categorie",  # Value is the name of the column that will hold the data
         -Boardgame,           # Ignore the Boardgame column, use every other column
         na.rm = TRUE) %>%     # Remove NA values
  arrange(Boardgame) %>%       # Sort by Boardgame
  select(-Cat_Label)           # Remove the unneeded Cat_Label column (if you want)

# Results:
   Boardgame Categorie
1      Game1 Deduction
2      Game1  Medieval
3      Game1 Word Game
4      Game2 Deduction
5      Game2  Medieval
6      Game3 Card Game
7      Game3  Medieval
8      Game3   Zombies
9      Game4    Horror
10     Game5    Horror
11     Game5  Medieval
12     Game5   Zombies
```

The `-boardgame` notation in the `gather` function means that every column but `Boardgame` will be gathered, even if you have 200 categorie columns. Once you have your data.frame, you can use `ggplot2` to visualize the `Categorie` column as you see fit.

It should be noted that development of `gather` by the Tidyverse team is complete. A new, more general function `pivot_longer` has been implemented to replace `gather`. It has similar usage in a simple case, but the arguments are a little different:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Boardgame,         # You now explicitly declare the columns
               names_to = "Cat_Label",    # New column containing old column names
               values_to = "Categorie",   # New column containing old column values
               values_drop_na = TRUE)     # Remove NA values
```